# Elastalert rule for CPU usage in percentage

Tags: elastalert

I am facing issue with elastalert rule for CPU usage (not load average). I am not getting any hit and match. Below is my .yaml file for CPU rule:

```
name: CPU usgae
type: metric_aggregation
index: metricbeat-*
buffer_time:
  minutes: 10
metric_agg_key: system.cpu.total.pct
metric_agg_type: avg
query_key: beat.hostname
doc_type: doc
bucket_interval:
  minutes: 5
sync_bucket_interval: true
max_threshold: 60.0
filter:
- term:
    metricset.name: cpu
alert:
- "email"
email:
- "xyz@xy.com"
```

Can you please help me what changes i need to make in my rule.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: For anyone coming here in 2020 and beyond change the ```metric_agg_key: system.cpu.total.norm.pct
apart from the percentage as mentioned in asnwer below

Answer (score 3):

Metricbeat reports CPU values in the range of 0 to 1. So a threshold of 60 will never be matched.

Try it with max_threshold: 0.6 and it probably will work.

Comment: I have made the changes as suggested by you. But still i am not getting any hit and alerts. My CPU usage is `100%` so it should get hit. I have checked on Kibana dashboard system.cpu.total.pct also showing 100%.

Comment: what does the original json look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing buffer_time and bucket_interval for testing

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug `elastalert` issue is by using command line option `--es_debug_trace` like this (`--es_debug_trace /tmp/output.txt`). It shows exact `curl` api call to `elasticsearch` being used by `elastalert` in background. Then the query can be copied and used in Kibana's Dev Tools for easy analysis and fiddling.

Most likely, `doc_type: doc` setting might have caused the ES endpoint to look like this: metricbeat-*/**doc**/_search
You might not have that **doc** document hence no match. Please remove doc_type and try.

Also please note that the pct value is less than 1 hence for you case: `max_threshold: 0.6`
For me following works, for your reference:

```
name: CPU usage

type: metric_aggregation

use_strftime_index: true
index: metricbeat-system.cpu-%Y.%m.%d

buffer_time:
  hour: 1

metric_agg_key: system.cpu.total.pct
metric_agg_type: avg
query_key: beat.hostname

min_doc_count: 1
  
bucket_interval:
  minutes: 5

max_threshold: 0.6

filter:
- term:
    metricset.name: cpu

realert:
  hours: 2
...
```

sample match output:

```
{
'@timestamp': '2021-08-19T15:06:22Z',
 'beat.hostname': 'MY_BUSY_SERVER',
 'metric_system.cpu.total.pct_avg': 0.6155,
 'num_hits': 50,
 'num_matches': 10
}
```